# developer console of browser shows wrong filename javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a simple library file is javascript, its ok while along but when there is jquery, all the console.log done in the file is shown as from jquery[image]

Edit: Recently I am working on a making simple library for canvas, which is going fine. To test the errors/outputs I am using console.log() function, seeing this in developer console it shows like this
[image]
But when jquery is also included the console shows jquery as file for the console send in another file, why is it? what the solution?

Comment: can you word your question better, kind of hard to understand.

Comment: library js file i m working on is here https://github.com/emp3ror/mvas/blob/master/src/mvas.0.1.js

Comment: I'm confused. is the causing an issue?

Comment: You mean, that when you log something in xxx.js, the logging seems to come from jQuery.1.1.js?

Comment: thanks for the link but your actual question, i dont think it makes sense.

Comment: Can you post your js file's code here so that we could know what you are actuelly trying to do ?

Comment: Thanks for quick response, i tried elaborating my question in edit :), the js files is the https://github.com/emp3ror/mvas/blob/master/src/mvas.0.1.js

Comment: @Teemu, yes thats what i mean

Comment: so what might be the solution??? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what your question is referring to but following statements might help you:

1.) Have you tried running your script without use of J Query library in any of your page? Does it show your script file?

2.) If by any chance the browser debugger is not able to find your script, try using this at the start of your script: "//# sourceURL=path/to/scriptFileName.js" -without quotes.

Hope it helps, cheers

Comment: tried //# sourceURL=path/to/scriptFileName.js dont know why, same thing is working in frens browser but not mine

Comment: You might try this with same browser and version as your friend did =)